# Insertion performance degrade with large index (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

Recently, i found that one of the server have high I/O traffic on disk. The high I/O due to the writing of index on certain table after some diagnostics. I have done several evaluation test and found that mysql take high number of write when inserting records to the table which have a large index.

The Data type of indexed columns is varchar(15) and varchar(17) ,both are non-unique index 
there is only 80 writes on disk if i load 20000 records to the table which has 10000 records whereas there are 1700 writes on disk when table grow to 20 millions (which got about 1 millions distinct values on indexed columns) 
even the number of records being inserted is the same.

Engine is MyISAM.

Increasing the size of the indexes also increasing number of write on disk per insert.

Is it the BTREE index behavior and how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Use InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

InnoDB helps by buffering writes to secondary indexes, merging them if possible, and delaying the expensive I/O.  You can read more about this feature in the MySQL Manual under [Controlling InnoDB Change Buffering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-performance-change_buffering.html).

---

Re your comment:

Inserting a new value into a B-Tree can be expensive.  If there's no room at the leaf level, the insertion may cause a cascading effect of splitting the non-leaf nodes of the tree, potentially all the way up to the top of the tree.  That can cause a lot of I/O, since different nodes of the tree may be stored far apart from one another on disk.

Other mitigating strategies are to make the table smaller, by moving less-used data to another table.  Or by using [MySQL table partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) to make the one logical table comprised of many individual physical tables.  Each such sub-table must have the same indexes, but then each individual index will be smaller.

---

There's an animated example here:
http://www.bluerwhite.org/btree/

Look at the example "Inserting Key 33 into a B-Tree (w/ Split)" where it shows the steps of inserting a value into a B-tree node that overfills it, and what the B-tree does in response.

Now imagine that the example illustration only shows the bottom part of a B-tree that is much deeper (as would be the case if your index B-tree has millions of entries), and filling the parent node can itself be an overflow, and force the splitting operation to continue up the the higher level in the tree.  This can continue all the way to the very top of the tree if all the ancestor nodes to the top of the tree were already filled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there any other possible way to reduce I/O on index writing since the table is in production environment and not prefer changing of its engine.  Also, is the expensive I/O is the nature of BTREE or any cause such circumstance.

Comment: Thanks so much for your clearly explain, that means the I/O due to the operation on splitting the nodes when there is an overflow of leaf node and it cost much when the tree grow?  As i am not really understand the algorithms of B-tree, this behavior append to all rdbms such as ORACLE (despite I/O on buffer)

Comment: I got it, thanks so much, but why primary index wont cause such issue?

Comment: The primary index *is* prone to this issue.  That's why using auto_increment primary key is good, because it always puts new values at the end of the index, and makes it less expensive to insert.